# How replace web with my own Angular Single Page App using Greasemonkey?

Tags: angular, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

How replace web html code with my own Angular Single Page App using Greasemonkey ?

Motivation: There is one very old website which needs redesign, but it's author does not care about. I would like to make Angular SPA application which replaces old html code of this website everytime its visited, and will be able to load and parse website's HTMLs data using Angular Service to present it in completely new and redesigned look in my Angular SPA. Compiled Angular SPA consists of one simple index.html and 4-5 js obfuscated files to be loaded into  html element. Is it possible somehow using Greasemonkey browser extension ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad. If you want to replace the old website with your own, you can replace the old head/body/… with your own with something like `document.body.innerHTML = …`
The real work here is to write that SPA and get the right data out of the old website.